# Cipher.getInstance is too slow

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

I have the following line of code that is taking less than a second on my computer (windows 7)  and about 20 seconds on a Redhat server :

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
```

where TRANSFORMATION is defind as :

```
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
```

What could be the source of such behaviour ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization of the Bouncy Castle provider and - probably - a slow `/dev/random`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I don't want you to be mislead by the mention of redhat and windows because I have also tested on another redhat and it is taking less than a second too.

Comment: A different CPU (e.g. a newer Intel) can already change the characteristics of `/dev/random`, so take a look at that.

Comment: In the case that /dev/random is slow what can I do about it ?

Comment: Check which applications use `/dev/random` and where possible switch them over to `/dev/urandom`. Or add devices that generate entropy for `/dev/random`. I had a similar issue on Ubuntu with a Java application. I'll check if there is an easy solution targeting Java. BTW you can easily check the speed of `/dev/random` by simply reading bytes from it (using `dd` command). Note that it *should* be a bit slow.

Comment: Its also happening in eclipse too. What can I do to fast it up?