# Java, groovy REST Clients slower then Postman over 30 times

Tags: java, rest, groovy, spring-web

I wrote REST client using springs `RestTemplate` in java and in groovy using 'HTTPBuilder'. Both invocation took **10 second** on my computer. In [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and other tools this kind the same post request it took **300 ms**.

This is simple invocation in groovy script. Essential is between `BEGIN REST invocation` and `END REST invocation`:

```
    @Grapes(
            @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7')
    )


    import groovy.json.JsonOutput
    import groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
    import groovy.transform.ToString
    import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

    import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
    import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST


    HTTPBuilder http = new HTTPBuilder()
    Forechart forechart = new Forechart(dayInterval: 3, adultCount: 1, childCount: 0,
                                        flightList: [new Flight(departureStation: "WAW", arrivalStation: "CRL", date: new Date(2018, 06, 02))
                                                    ,new Flight(departureStation: "CRL", arrivalStation: "WAW", date: new Date(2018, 10, 26))])

    def jsonRequest = JsonOutput.toJson( forechart )
    LazyMap jsonResponse



    //BEGIN REST invocation
        println "Request: " + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(jsonRequest)
        long start = System.nanoTime()

        http.request( 'https://be.wizzair.com/7.15/Api/asset/farechart', POST, JSON ) { req ->
            body = jsonRequest
            headers.Accept = 'application/json'

            response.success = { resp, json ->
                assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
                jsonResponse = json
            }

            response.'404' = {
                println 'Not found'
            }
        }

        long end = System.nanoTime() - start

        //println "Response: $jsonResponse"
        println "\nDuration: " + end / 1_000_000_000 + " seconds"
    //END REST invocation



    ForechartFlights forechartFlights = new ForechartFlights(jsonResponse)
    //Data Objects
    @ToString(includePackage = false)
    class Forechart {
        boolean wdc
        List<Flight> flightList
        int dayInterval
        int adultCount
        int childCount
        boolean isRescueFare
    }

    @ToString(includePackage = false)
    class Flight {
        String departureStation
        String arrivalStation
        Date date
    }


    //response

    @ToString(includePackage = false)
    class ForechartFlights {
        List<ForechartFlight> outboundFlights
        List<ForechartFlight> returnFlights
    }

    @ToString(includePackage = false)
    class ForechartFlight {
        String departureStation
        String arrivalStation
        String priceType
        String classOfService
        boolean hasMacFlight
        Date date
        Price price;

    }

    @ToString(includePackage = false)
    class Price {
        BigDecimal amount
        String currencyCode
    }
```

What is reason?

Answer (score 7):

It seems this request takes a good while (8+ seconds) using curl as well:

```
~> time curl -v -d "@post.data" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://be.wizzair.com/7.14.0/Api/asset/farechart

*   Trying 104.122.232.212...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to be.wizzair.com (104.122.232.212) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: wizzair.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> POST /7.14.0/Api/asset/farechart HTTP/1.1
> Host: be.wizzair.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 407
>
* upload completely sent off: 407 out of 407 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: -1
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Server:
< Date: Sun, 27 May 2018 18:07:43 GMT
< Content-Length: 10023
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=hnrxfwuxvkxo34k3zhcljnce; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: _abck=83611DFC82637AC8726723372C6A8EFC50EFF7BD2A040000EFF30A5B01AC6952~-1~Ip07wEKIXzwehsarZ0eh+sBBuiiRDje8DAQpi80fdXk=~-1~-1; expires=Mon, 27 May 2019 18:07:43 GMT; max-age=31536000; path=/; domain=.wizzair.com
< Set-Cookie: bm_sz=41F805925F8BB0BCFE47CBE64B3531A2~QAAQvffvUJsv45ZjAQAAId/IorrnukpLPnmZ8H7WRPTEdCk0rMrrIOdi+wLlRh3DFodvGU9Mu5gq0MDfhTtHxwo4hm0DC2IT5Ql6PrXWlY59p5wf57bBed+P4Lq5+bX7XtlNRFTFda9yjVVzYbgknJ30w8JOrE2prYAGu1mh/9qkFPzvKkJXjGcz7QA8eLUS; Domain=.wizzair.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 27 May 2018 22:07:35 GMT; Max-Age=14392; HttpOnly
<
<snip>response data here</snip>
real  0m8.386s
user  0m0.024s
sys 0m0.022s
```

Where I saved the request data in a file `post.data` first.

I would suspect that there is some header or other detail in the request that is not identical between the invocations that take a long time (like this curl and the groovy example) and the ones that do not.

If you are using a tool like Postman, check the request headers and see if there is something we are not sending in the ones that take a long time.

**update after further testing**

I have verified this with postman as well (i.e. fast with postman, slow with java and curl) and no difference in headers. I am fairly convinced this has to do with the handling of https and TLSv1.2.

A potential though perhaps far out culprit might be the reported slow (non-hardware accelerated) AES GCM encryption that TLSv1.2 (which is used by the site as per the above curl trace) allows:

[Java Server, TLSv1.1 fast, TLSv1.2 extremely slow (90MByte/sec versus 4MByte/sec)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577804/java-server-tlsv1-1-fast-tlsv1-2-extremely-slow-90mbyte-sec-versus-4mbyte-sec)

[Slow AES GCM encryption and decryption with Java 8u20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992131/slow-aes-gcm-encryption-and-decryption-with-java-8u20)

**update 2 after some more forensics**

by sending in the following flag to groovy (or java) when running the test:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

we can see that the client script receives the encrypted data:

```
<snip a ton of network and tls detail>
05B0: 9E EA 98 06 6B 91 EC 2A   76 C8 F3 39 81 88 C5 30  ....k..*v..9...0
05C0: 02 34 45 E9 8C 12 EE 07   E3 31 C7 5C 8F DB FD C9  .4E......1.\....
05D0: 80 F4 0A F7 B4 57 CC 68   EF 96 70 7C 5E B6        .....W.h..p.^.
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 1502
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 1478
0000: 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31   20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D  HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
0010: 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74   2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61  .Content-Type: a
0020: 70 70 6C 69 63 61 74 69   6F 6E 2F 6A 73 6F 6E 3B  pplication/json;
0030: 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74   3D 75 74 66 2D 38 0D 0A   charset=utf-8..
00
<snip - HttpOnly is the end of the last response cookie, after that 
I'm assuming the encrypted data starts> 
0410: 3B 20 48 74 74 70 4F 6E   6C 79 0D 0A 0D 0A 1F 8B  ; HttpOnly......
0420: 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03   CD 98 C1 4A C3 40 14 45  ...........J.@.E
0430: FF 65 D6 09 CC 4C 6D D4   EC A4 E2 AA 45 B0 85 2E  .e...Lm.....E...
<snip - more encrypted data>
0590: 1C 78 6E C4 5E C0 16 39   F0 DC 68 77 99 22 C7 16  .xn.^..9..hw."..
05A0: 39 EC DC B0 45 0E CC 46   BC 2F 60 8B 1C 78 6E C4  9...E..F./`..xn.
05B0: FB 02 B6 C8 81 E7 46 BC   2F 9C 5D E4 4E 6F FC FF  ......F./.].No..
05C0: 20 5E 27 27 00 00                                   ^''..
<THIS IS WHERE WE HANG FOR A LONG TIME>
Duration: 10.904149839 seconds
```

(well we see a ton of output, but at the end we receive the encrypted data)

and then just hangs there for a long time.

In other words, it is not the receiving of the data or the server taking a long time. We already have the data and then hang.

I'm assuming this is the decryption of the received data taking time and I would attribute it to the above slow decryption or some similar issue with java ssl.

Not rock solid, but seems at least a plausible theory.

Assuming the above theory holds we are still left wondering why curl is slow.