# GCS slow upload from pod inside kubernetes GKE

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Uploading to GCE from a pod inside GKE takes really long. I hoped the upgrade to kubernetes 1.1 would help, but it didn't. It is faster, but not as fast as it should be. I made some benchmarks, uploading a single file with 100MiB:

- docker 1.7.2 local

  took {20m51s240ms}, that's about ~{0.07993605115907274}MB/s
- docker 1.8.3 local

  took {3m51s193ms}, that's about ~{0.4329004329004329}MB/s
- docker 1.9.0 local

  took {3m51s424ms}, that's about ~{0.4329004329004329}MB/s
- kubernetes 1.0

  took {1h10s952ms}, that's about ~{0.027700831024930747}MB/s
- kubernetes 1.1.2 (docker 1.8.3)

  took {32m11s359ms}, that's about ~{0.05178663904712584}MB/s

As you can see the thruput doubles with kubernetes 1.1.2, but is still really slow. If I want to upload 1GB I have to wait for ~5 hours, this can't be the expected behaviour. GKE runs inside the Google infrastructure, so I expect that it should be faster or at least as fast as uploading from local.

I also noted a very high CPU load (70%) while uploading. It was tested with a `n1-highmem-4` machine-type and a single RC/pod that was doing nothing then the upload.

I'm using the java client with the GAV coordinates `com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.5`

The relevant code is as follows:

```
InputStream inputStream = ...; // 100MB RandomData from RAM
StorageObject so = new StorageObject().setContentType("text/plain").setName(objectName);
AbstractInputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent("text/plain", inputStream);
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
storage.objects().insert(bucket.getName(), so, content).execute();
watch.stop();
```

Copying a 100MB file using a manually installed gcloud with `gsutil cp` took nearly no time (3 seconds). So it might be an issue with the java-library? The question still remains, how to improve the upload time using the java-library?

Comment: Did you try to use gsutil [1] to upload? if it's still slow, you can use gsutil perfdiag -o output.json gs://your-bucket for verbosity. 

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Comment: @George Thank for your suggestion. It turns out that using gsutil is quite fast. But to use that I have to install gsutil and authorization into the container, which can't be the intention of the kubernetes concept. But it narrows the issue to the java-library.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to enable "DirectUpload", so instead of writing

```
storage.objects().insert(bucket.getName(), so, content).execute();
```

you have to write:

```
    Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(bucket.getName(), so, content);
    insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
    insert.execute();
```

Performance I get with this solution:

- took {13s515ms}, that's about ~{7.6923076923076925}MB/s

JavaDoc for the `setDirectUploadEnabled`:

> Sets whether direct media upload is enabled or disabled.
>
> If value is set to true then a direct upload will be done where the
>   whole media content is uploaded in a single request. If value is set
>   to false then the upload uses the resumable media upload protocol to
>   upload in data chunks.
>
> Direct upload is recommended if the content size falls below a certain
>   minimum limit. This is because there's minimum block write size for
>   some Google APIs, so if the resumable request fails in the space of
>   that first block, the client will have to restart from the beginning
>   anyway.
>
> Defaults to false.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're seeing high CPU load and that the slowness only affects Java and not the Python `gsutil` is consistent with the [slow AES GCM issue in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992131/slow-aes-gcm-encryption-and-decryption-with-java-8u20). The issue is fixed in Java 9 [using appropriate specialized CPU instructions](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046943).

If you have control over it, then either using Java 7 or adding `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3,GCM` to a file passed to `java -Djava.security.properties` should fix the slowness as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318179/3777211) to the general slow AES GCM question.

Comment: Nice catch, I tried that, but unfortunatly it did not worked. The opposite is the case, if I add GCM to the disabled Algorithms, it slows down (about 40%), the SSLv3 has no effect. Tested with Oracle JDK 8u65/Linux 64bit.

Comment: Ah, interesting. There's another thing related to SSL which we do elsewhere, and could also be consistent with being Java-specific, which is additionally in the java.security.properties file, to set: `securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom`; default is /dev/random, and if it exhausts the entropy pool then things grind to a halt. http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ explains why it's not actually insecure to use /dev/urandom

Comment: Thank you for the insight, but unfortunatly it did not helped, which matches this article: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html