# AES GCM with hardware accelerated support before Java 9

Tags: java, performance, encryption, cryptography, aes-gcm

My use case involves encrypting large amounts of sensitive data on the order of petabytes using AES with GCM in Java and I will need high throughput to make that task complete in reasonable time.

As was [previously asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27028067) on here, AES/GCM is still severely crippled in the latest JDK 8 (~**17MB/s** on my hardware). I'm happy to know that [JEP 246](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/246) for adding [significant hardware acceleration for GCM](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/attachment/25422/GCM%20Analysis.pdf) made it onto the roadmap for Java 9, however General Availability for the next major Java release has been pushed out to over a year away as of me writing this.

So far the fastest implementation I have found is the Bouncy Castle Provider, with no hardware acceleration and throughput on the order of **170MB/s**. I know that my hardware supports acceleration by running benchmarks of the native libraries **GnuTLS** (*gnutls-cli --benchmark-ciphers*) and **OpenSSL** (*openssl speed -evp aes-128-gcm*), both clocking in at over **2GB/s** for AES/GCM. Unfortunately I can't find a current Java wrapper around either of these. The closest I've come across is [Apache JuiCE](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/juice.html), built on OpenSSL, but it was abandoned over 8 years ago.

Has anyone come across a JCE Provider that supports hardware acceleration for AES/GCM that I could use in the near term, either commercial or open source?

Comment: OpenSSL API is rather straightforward; even better than JCE. You could easily make JNI wrappers for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Netty-tcnative](http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html) provides an alternative SSL engine using JNI to interface with native OpenSSL. You should be able to access the crypto functions directly in a similar way. That said, [JEP 246: Leverage CPU Instructions for GHASH and RSA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm) is now part of Java 9, so you should be able to get similar performance without resorting to native code.