# Java SSLSocket inefficient GCM

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, aes-gcm

I am using Java's SSLSocket with cipher suite: **TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

Which turned out to be very inefficient.

I want to still use the above cipher suite and override the Java's default algorithm with my implementation.

What is the best practice ? :

1. Override SSLSocket
2. Override SunJSSE provider
3. Other methods...

Comment: Turned out to be very inefficient how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992131/slow-aes-gcm-encryption-and-decryption-with-java-8u20