# Java System.loadLibrary does not lookup in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ folder for library

Tags: java, c++, linux, wildfly

Oracle Java 1.8 does not lookup `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder to load native library.

I have installed OpenSSL library, which is installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder, however while loading from Java using `System.loadLibrary()`, only lookup path were

```
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Am I missing some configuration? Updating env `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works <strike>but preferred programmatic approach to avoid additional steps.</strike>

### EDIT

Agreed. programmatic hack is not sustainable option. Running native executable does loads library from the arch `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder. Java not looking in arch folder.

Comment: Why use a programmatic approach? The location may change if you run on another system, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes that is true, but setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH may not be feasible when shipping jar file.

Comment: Why do you think you need to load the OpenSSL library? when SSL and JCE are built into the JRE?

Comment: Java 8 with GCM mode has performance issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992131/slow-aes-gcm-encryption-and-decryption-with-java-8u20

Answer (score 0):

I think that programmatic way is bad idea.
What you will be doing on another platforms???

I see two ways to solve this problem

1. Using LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. Create symlink in standard directories for your library

Comment: Let me rephrase, By programmatic i mean was to avoid additional configuration step.  Basically, how Java skips the lookup in the arch folder?